# Add 3rd server with pglogical replication to a 2 server cluster with stream sync replication and failsafe with patroni

Tags: postgresql, failovercluster, database-replication, patroni

I have 3 servers with Ubuntu 19.10, PostgreSQL 12.2 and Patroni 1.6.4 and I would like to have the following setup:

I want to have two servers with synchronised replication
and I want to add a 3rd server with pglogical replication just to accept inserts to specific tables. no DELETE, TRUNCATE or anything else.

I log a huge amount of purchases per day, around 300M.
I want to have to servers to already have the purchases history of the last 30 days,
and the 3rd server which has a really big storage, will hold all the history of the purchases.

So far I have a patroni cluster with etcd for the 2 servers with the following configuration:

This is for the first and 2nd server I have the following configuration, of course the name of the server differs in each configuration:

```
scope: patroni_cluster_1
name: server_X

restapi:
  listen: 0.0.0.0:8008
  connect_address: X.X.X.X:8008

etcd:
  hosts: X.X.X.X:2379
  protocol: http

bootstrap:
  dcs:
    ttl: 30
    loop_wait: 10
    retry_timeout : 10
    maximum_lag_on_failover: 1048576
    postgresql:
      use_pg_rewind: true
      use_slots: true
      parameters:
        wal_keep_segments: 100

  initdb:
  - encoding: UTF8
  - data-checksums

  pg_hba:
  - host replication replicator 0.0.0.0/0 md5
  - host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5

postgresql:
  listen: 0.0.0.0:5432
  connect_address: X.X.X.X:5432
  synchronous_mode: true
  synchronous_mode_strict: false
  data_dir: /var/lib/postgresql/patroni_cluster_1/server_X/data
  bin_dir: /usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin
  authentication:
    replication:
      username: replicator
      password: XXXX
    superuser:
      username: postgres
      password: XXXX
  parameters:
    shared_preload_libraries: pglogical
```

I added pglogical as a shared library because of the 3rd server which I would like to know if I can fully setup with Patroni.

I read about how to setup pglogical with https://blog.dbi-services.com/postgresql-logical-replication-with-pglogical/ and I would like to know if I can fully configure the 3rd server with pglogical for inserts only.

I'm new to Patroni and I'm pretty lost so any information regarding this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only method I found to do that is to create a bash script that executes psql commands that configure pglogical.

so I added a post_bootstrap property to the yaml as stated here: https://github.com/zalando/patroni/blob/master/docs/SETTINGS.rst

the bash script receives the datbase dsn as parameters, I use it to connect to it and configure what I please.

as far as I know there no way to configure pglogical directly from patroni.